# Constructor not defined Error

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I write this code in Main.java class but the program not run. Why? the program has error of `Intent i=new Intent(this,Location.class);` what is the problem??

```
package org.example.loyaltier;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Main extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;
private Button mHome;
private Button mProduct;
private Button mPlaces;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    mHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_home);
    mProduct=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_product);
    mPlaces=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_places);

    mHome.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);


}
private OnClickListener onClickListener=new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_home:
            mWebView.loadUrl      ("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/code/home/home.php");
            break;
        case R.id.button_product:
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://loyaltier.com/app/mobile/design/catalog/catalog1.php");
            break;
        case R.id.button_places:
            Intent i=new Intent(this,Location.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
};
}
```

The problems is :  `The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<Location>) is undefined`  but i don't understand what is the problem and how can I solve this?

Please help me fast ;)

LogCat::

```
10-31 11:35:04.135: D/AndroidRuntime(16626): Shutting down VM
10-31 11:35:04.135: W/dalvikvm(16626): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a3e1f8)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Places(View) in the activity class org.example.loyaltier.Main for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_places'
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3026)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Places [class android.view.View]
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3019)
10-31 11:35:04.159: E/AndroidRuntime(16626):    ... 11 more
10-31 11:35:04.190: D/dalvikvm(16626): GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 3% free 14282K/14599K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-31 11:35:09.057: I/Process(16626): Sending signal. PID: 16626 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` in the `new Intent(this,Location.class);` refers to the instance of the anonymous `View.OnClickListener` object. You need to supply an instance of the `Context`. Try:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Main.this,Location.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I change this to Main.this but when i clicked in the places button or product button, the program stopeed. Why? I write LogCat in first post.

Comment: @PariyaDaghoghi that's another question

Comment: you mean i asked this, in another page?

Comment: yes, it is better to ask it as a new question, and also don't forget to post the layout XML in the new question.

Comment: I don't understand what do u mean. I use case and check id for when user clicks on the button. What should i add to my program?

Comment: mHome.setOnClickListener(onClickListener); its only call from your  java. same you have to call mProduct.setOnClickListener (onClickListener); and mPlaces.setOnClickListener(onClickListener); hope you get it

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot. but when i clicked places button the program has stopped. Why? now home button and product button are ok.Do need for Location class?

Comment: of course you have to . have to change main,this instead .this and have you add location class in manifest as activity. ?

Comment: Its my pleasure.most of time developer did same mistake . remind me if you have any query i will try to help.